# Illegal assignment from list<event> to sobject

Tags: trigger, custom-field, sobject

I'm writing a trigger to update the activity field-contact_sys_id__C with the value of sys id /siebel id depending on the if type field.

```
trigger ContactSysID on Event (before insert) {
    Id evid;

    for(event e : trigger.new){
        evid = e.whatid;
    }

    event e = [select id,contact_sys_id__c from event where whatid = :evid];

    Merchandise__c merch = [SELECT 
        TYPEOF What
            WHEN Merchandise__C THEN name,id_type__C,sys_id__c,siebel_id__C
        END
        FROM event where WHAT.TYPE = 'Merchandise__c' limit 1];

    for (Merchandise__C m : merch){
        if(m.id_type__C == 'Sys ID'){
            e.Contact_sys_ID__c = m.sys_id__c;
        }
        else{
            e.contact_sys_id__C = m.siebel_id__C;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the issue with more details like where you get the error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're running a query that could return mutliple events, i.e. a `List<Event>` and trying to assigning to Event reference that's singular:

```
event e=[select id,contact_sys_id__c from event where whatid=:evid];
```

What you need to do is either use a reference to a list (and then subsequently deal with all of the elements in it):

```
List<event> events = [select id,contact_sys_id__c from event where whatid=:evid];
```

Or, if you're sure there should only be one result, just stick a `limit 1` in there:

```
event e=[select id,contact_sys_id__c from event where whatid=:evid limit 1];
```

Comment: Also look at bulkifying your trigger to cater for multiple events inserted at a time, not only 1.

Comment: Thanks. The query is working now. But I face another problem now. If I try to create an event for Contact object, this trigger is fired and it is working perfectly fine. But when I create an event for some other object eg Merchandise object, then also the below trigger is getting fired and it displays error and the event is not saved.

How can I restrict the below trigger to work only for Contact object and not get fired for other objects.

Comment: You'll need to check the SObject type that `WhatId` relates to and only handle it if it matches what you want. Ids have a method called get SObjectType that you'll want to use. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_Id_getSObjectType